# Slim dynamic route creation

Tags: php, session, routes, slim

I am trying to creating a site which has different `siteId` for every user so i what i did i am giving every different `url` (`/s/{site_id}`) so whenever they hit the route `siteid` will be stored in the `session` and that `siteid` is used later in different route. So when user hit the site url for the first time shows 
`//login` blank `siteid` but when i hit the `url` for the second it works correctly or if change the `siteid` then it will show the first `siteid` i entered. Anyone please help me out

```
   $app->get('/s/{site_id}', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
        $session = new \SlimSession\Helper;
        if (!isset($session->siteId)) {
            $session->siteId = $args['site_id'];
        }
        $url = $this->router->pathFor('login', [$session->siteId]);
        return $response->withRedirect($url);
    })->setName('switch');
    app->group('/' . $session->siteId, function () {
        $this->get('/login', 'LoginController:index')->setName('userIndex');
    });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you define any other variable named `$session` except the one you're using in `/s/{site_id}` route? I think in your group routes trying to access `$session->siteId` should raise `Trying to get property of non-objectl` error.

Comment: @Nima it shows route not defined (page not found) error